# How to create an adjacency matrix of mutual friendships from facebook in python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-fql, adjacency-matrix

I am doing a project on Social Network Analysis of Facebook Network. I had to get all my friends and who of my friends are friends with each other, mutual frindships inside my network. I did that, I got all id's of my friends and adjacencies and now I have to form an adjacency matric which indicates if 2 of my friends are friends. For example:
A and B are friends, A and C are friends, but B and C are not friends. This would look like this:

```
  A  B  C

A 0  1  1

B 1  0  0

C 1  0  0
```

Because I have the list of id's and adjacencies already in python, I should also do the matrix in python, so if you have any ideas or a basic algorithm how to enter 1's and 0's I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, it just required 2 for loops to go thorugh the list and compare whether the users id is in the adjacency list, if that is the case, make that entry 1, otherwise 0.

Comment: Congrats on the solution!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others might learn from your success.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

I think this structure is better implemented as a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_network_graph). For example, take a look at [NetworkX](https://web.archive.org/web/20121115182146/http://networkx.lanl.gov:80/).

Anyway, if you really need matrices, a matrix can simply be implement as a list of lists, like this:

```
m = [[0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 0],
     [1, 0, 0],]
```

But if you intend to do any matrix manipulation, you should check out the [numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) library.

Comment: I actually already have a graph(rGraph), but what I need is such a matrix because it is easier for me and my team to analyze triadic and other patterns of friendships in the data.

Comment: I'm not positive, but he might've meant an adjacency matrix implementation of a graph, which could be useful here potentially.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Data_structures

Comment: @EnsarJusufovic You should check out the python NetworkX package along with the numpy package. You have a function to get the numpy adjacency matrix from your graph: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_numpy_matrix.html#networkx.convert.to_numpy_matrix

Comment: I've read the article, and yes, this is what I need. But I am new to python and don't really know how to create this matrix, I have the necessary data, the basic idea would be:
create a matrix of size no. of friends x no. of friends
for each column (friend id) compare where the adjacency exists and put 1, else 0 etc
Something like this..:S

Comment: The problem is that I took a template for the graph, just entered the data and the graph was created automatically, it is not a graph created using the networkx package.

Comment: @EnsarJusufovic So what data structure do your have right now? And what kind of operations do you intend to do with the adjacency matrix? You should complete your question with these clarifications.

Comment: I have a list, one part of it:
{
          o
            -
            "adjacencies": [
                + "100000443827110",
                + "1156934043"
            ],
          o
            -
            "data": {
                + "connections": "NN.<br>NN.",
                + "normalized_popularity": 0.005847953216374269,
            },
          o "id": "100000680047152",
          o "name": "NN."
      },
The important part of it is the id at the end and the adjacencies, this is done for all of my friends. I am the data extractor, another team member will be doing the analysis.

Comment: I still think it's worth going the extra mile and converting this list to a NetworkX graph. It may turn out to be even easier than converting it to an adjacency matrix. Once you have a NetworkX graph, you can easily get an adjacency matrix in several formats (numpy matrix, SciPy sparse matrix [COO, LIL, DOK...]). Which format is better for you depends on what operations the analysis is going to require.

Comment: I am thinking about that option, but I don't know how this is going to work, because it becomes a heavy graph, there are 500+ nodes(friends), but I will see about that. Thank you for your help, I appreciate it.